# Misuse of slices in Go

Tags: go

I'm working on some code to find all palindromes from a string:

```
func palindrome(s string) bool {
    for i, j := 0, len(s) - 1; i < j; i, j = i + 1, j - 1 {
        if s[i] != s[j] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func dfs(s string, start int, sol *[][]string, curr *[]string) {
    if start == len(s) {
        *sol = append(*sol, *curr)
        fmt.Println("intermediate value:", *sol)
        return
    }
    
    for i := start + 1; i <= len(s); i++ {
        substr := s[start:i]
        if palindrome(substr) {
            *curr = append(*curr, substr)
            dfs(s, i, sol, curr)
            *curr = (*curr)[:len(*curr) - 1]
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    sol := [][]string{} 
    dfs("aab", 0, &sol, new([]string))
    fmt.Println("last value:", sol)
}
```

The program outputs:

```
intermediate value: [[a a b]]
intermediate value: [[aa b b] [aa b]]
last value: [[aa b b] [aa b]]
```

Looks like when function `dfs()` returns, `sol` gets corrupted and its first element changes from [a a b] to [aa b b].

I can't figure out what's wrong with how I declare and use parameters `sol` and `curr`.

Comment: When in doubt, the bug is not in the compiler or runtime -- there is no memory corruption here. I suggest you read through https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Comment: Thanks for the link. I also updated the tile to make it clear that I'm not saying Go has a bug, just my code.

Comment: @agshe If you read through the link JimB shared, you will find your answer under [Slice Internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro#slice-internals): `Slicing does not copy the slice’s data. It creates a new slice value that points to the original array. This makes slice operations as efficient as manipulating array indices. Therefore, modifying the elements (not the slice itself) of a re-slice modifies the elements of the original slice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments posted by JimB and Ricardo Souza, the fix is an extra append needed when updating `*sol`:

```go
*sol = append(*sol, append([]string{}, (*curr)...))
```

This code change makes a copy of the contents of `*curr`.

Also, `curr` doesn't need to be a pointer type.